# how to combine the matrices that are output by the for loop in r

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to combine matrices which are output by for loop over all variables inside a function in R?
lets say I have `179=length(b)` variables, and each variable gives a matrix has `2000 rows=nrow(data.test)` and `28 columns=length(x2)`.
The final matrix should have `rows=nrow(data.test)`times `length(x2) * (ncol(data.test)-1)` 
I tried for loop as follows but the values did not store in the last matrix

```
  MyFunction <- function(data.train,x2,no.sample,data.test )
{  pre_var  = matrix(,nrow = nrow(data.test), ncol = length(x2) * (ncol(data.test)-1))
for( b in 1:(ncol(data.test)-1))
{  false= NULL ; true=NULL
  pred_test = matrix(,nrow = nrow(data.test), ncol = length(x2))
  for(w in 1:length(x2))
  {  ## there are some lines here to produce false and true values

    pred_test[,w] = as.numeric(ifelse(data.test[,b] > x2[w] 
                                      ,true[w] ,false[w]))}
  pre_var = cbind(pre_var,pred_test)
}
results = NULL
results = pre_var
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to put it in a list first... and then perform cbind. Maybe that allows you to debug it easier

Comment: Do you mean like this pre_var = list(cbind(pre_var,pred_test) mean like this )

Comment: @Amani Are you sure about the logic? `true <- NULL; true[5]` (the reult is always `NULL`)

Comment: Thank you for replaying, but there are some line before the pred_test  matrix to produce false and true values

Comment: @Amani, that is not what I meant... check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's for the sake of simplicity assume that this is a matrix of one of your results

```
A = matrix(runif(9),ncol=3)
```

What you want to do, is put them in a list first. In this setting I just repeat my original matrix. In your case you of course generate your matrices

```
A_list = rep(list(A),5)
```

The next step is to cbind these together. Here we have a simple cbind-forloop.

```
n <- length(A_list)
res <- NULL
for(i in seq(n)){
    res <- cbind(res, A_list[[i]])
}
res
```

Et Voila, I think this is what you wanted.